# Liang-Barsky Line Clipping Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, clipping

Is it possible to generalize Liang-Barsky Line Clipping Algorithm for n-dimensional space ?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing specific for 2D case in this algorithm idea, so Liang-Barsky Line Clipping Algorithm could be generalized for 3D and n-dimensional space.
For 3D you have to find parameters of intersection with 6 planes, checking their range.

[Citation:](https://www.siggraph.org/education/materials/HyperGraph/scanline/clipping/cliplb.htm)

```
Liang-Barsky Algorithm
The relative speed improvement over Sutherland-Cohen algorithm is as follows:

36% for 2D lines
 40% for 3D lines
 70% for 4D lines
```